# iOS app to make interval photos

Tags: ios, photography

All apps I'm trying are to make timelapse videos they render by themselves. I want an app that take photos at regular intervals and store them in Photo albums.

BTH, for Android it is not that different. "A full featured app for creating stunning time-lapse videos". I don't want rendered videos, I just want single still images.

Comment: Can't believe there's no app to take photos at regular intervals, not creating a video

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Apple Workflow.
Created a new one.

1. Repeat (open)
2. Set Brightness to minimum (to spend battery as less as possible) (this item can be #1)
3. Take Photo.  Show Camera Preview Off
4. Rotate Image 90
5. Resize (optional)
6. Set Name
7. Save to Photo Album
8. Wait XX seconds
9. End Repeat
10. Set Brightness to desired
11. Exit Workflow